# How can I save the session and cookies in a Rails app using Mechanize to handle a URL, and store the values in a rails session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, mechanize

I want to save the session of a url that I handle using Mechanize, in a rails app. My current code is:

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
if params[:more].to_i == 1
  @agent.cookie_jar.load session[:jar]
end
page = @agent.get(url)

@agent.cookie_jar.save_as session[:jar], :session => true
```

This seemed to work fine, but then i realized that this cookie was being saved in the root directory of my project, which was not fine. How can I save the session and cookies of the Url accessed with Mechanize into a rails session?